# What happens if I move a local Git repo that has already been pushed?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a local Git repo that has already been pushed to some remote repository. What happens if I move that local repo to another local directory?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely nothing. The remote will still be tracked, and everything will still work.

You can safely move git-tracked directories (as long as the `.git` directory inside moves along with everything else)

Comment: After moving the directory locally, what would `git status` show?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nothing, no new changes. That's, again, assuming you're moving the entire directory, including `.git`.