# Moving entire git repo directory

Tags: git

If you have a Git repo on Windows at `c:\mydir\myrepo` can you just move the entire `myrepo` directory to say `d:\blah\myrepo`?

I'm assuming the `myrepo\.git` configuration directory is relative to the parent so you can move the entire directory without any issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens if I move a local Git repo that has already been pushed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231243/what-happens-if-i-move-a-local-git-repo-that-has-already-been-pushed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: yes. If you move the entire directory, including it's `.git` folder, git will continue functioning on the project and you'd be able to continue working with it without issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can move it just fine.  As long as that `.git` folder is included, git will think it's a repository.